# Prisma: Create-if-not-exists multiple explicit many-to-many relations in one query

Tags: javascript, orm, prisma

I have `Playlist` and `Video` models, with an *explicit* many-to-many relationship (to hold extra data). Say in my server code, I have an array of `Video` primary keys, **how do I add these videos to a playlist, if they aren't already in it?**

My closest working example is this. To my understanding, `upsert` is actually a "create-if-not-exists, otherwise update" operation, but with an empty object for `update` thus working similarly to what I want (albeit slightly more complicated). However, here I am only adding 1 video to the playlist at once. Is there a way to add *multiple* videos (aka creating multiple many-to-many relations to the join table between `Playlist` & `Video`), ideally in one query?

```
const id = /* Playlist's ID */
const videoUrl = /* Video's Url, which is its primary key */
// I want to use an array of videoUrls instead, not just 1

const updatedPlaylist = await prisma.playlist.update({
  where: { id },
  include: { videos: { include: { video: true } } },
  data: {
    videos: {
      upsert: {
        where: {
          playlistId_videoUrl: {
            playlistId: id,
            videoUrl: videoUrl,
          },
        },
        create: {
          addedAt: new Date(),
          video: {
            connect: { url: videoUrl },
          },
        },
        update: {},
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I've tried reading Prisma docs, but there's too many different APIs and I got confused, even regarding where to start the query from (do I `update` the Playlist model and create multiple join relations? Do I `updateMany` the Video model and for each also create a join relation? Or do I `create` the join relation first, then somehow `connect` them to the Playlist and Video models on both sides?)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once, my solution was deleting all the rows in the join table and then add them again.

```
   const create = [];
data.videos.forEach((video) => {
  create.push({
    video: {
      connect: {
        url: videos.url,
      },
    },
  });
});

const playlist = await this.prisma.playlist.update({
  where: { id: data.id },
  data: {
    ...data,
    videos: {
      deleteMany: {
        playlist_id: id,
      },
      create,
    },
    updated_at: new Date(),
  },
 
});
```

in the previous code you can update the extra data in the join table row and remove video from the playlist too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this seems hacky... I don't think this kind of relatively simple DB operation requires deleting and re-adding an entire playlist's join relations.
For now, I've tried making 2 queries: 1 to get the list of videoUrls that already relate to the current playlist, then filter those out of the request's incoming videoUrls (so they end up only containing videoUrls for *new* relations), and then a 2nd query to create those new relations without worrying about duplicates. This works so far, though it does require 2 round trips to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

### Prisma Documentation Says it is not Possible

According to the Prisma documentation this is not currently possible.

It leads you through this fun rabbit hole:

- https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#create-multiple-records
- https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#create-records-and-connect-or-create-related-records
- https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#create-multiple-records-and-multiple-related-records

### The Next Best Thing

I really do not like this option, but I believe the next best thing you could do would be to separate this out into multiple queries.

#### Setting the Scene

I'm going to go with the idea of `Merchants` and `Transactions` where transactions have a merchant, and that merchant may or may not exist yet but is required for the transaction.

Here's an example schema:

```
model Merchant {
  id          String        @id @default(uuid())
  name        String        @unique
  Transaction Transaction[]
}

model Transaction {
  id          String   @id @default(uuid())
  merchantId  String
  merchant    Merchant @relation(fields: [merchantId], references: [id])
  description String
}
```

#### Some Raw Data

Some example data of what we are working with.

```
const transactions = [
  {
    id: '1',
    description: 'Transaction 1',
    merchantName: 'Merchant 1',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    description: 'Transaction 2',
    merchantName: 'Merchant 2',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    description: 'Transaction 3',
    merchantName: 'Merchant 1',
  },
]
```

#### First Insert Your Relations

```
// Get a unique collection of merchant names
const merchantNames = new Set(transactions.map((transaction) => transaction.merchantName))

// Note this only returns the created records that are not duplicates
await prisma.merchants.createMany({
  data: merchantNames,
  skipDuplicates: true // So it does not crash on a duplicate
})
```

### Collect Relevant Merchants and Create a Fast Lookup

This ends up working out since the merchant names are unique and thus can utilize the name to lookup the ID.

```
const merchants = await prisma.merchant.findMany({
  // Note: use a select here if there's additional data not relevant to this
  where: {
    name: {
      in: merchantNames
    }
  },
})

const merchantsTuples = merchants.map((merchant) => [
  merchant.name, // This will be the lookup key to the id
  merchant.id, // This is the relationship id
])

const merchantLookup = new Map(merchantsTuples)
```

### Create Many Transactions Using Merchant Lookup

```
const createManyTransactionsData = transactions.map(({
  description,
  merchantName,
}) => ({
  description,
  merchant_id: merchantLookup.get(merchantName),
}))

await prisma.transactions.createMany({
  data: createManyTransactionsData,
  skipDuplicates: true // Important if you're trying to reconcile data that may already exist
})
```